# Recenter Chart after zoom and\or pan

Tags: achartengine

Is there a way to re-center the chart after a user has zoomed in\out or panned the chart?  I would like to give the user the ability to be able to get the chart back to its original zoomed and panned view.  Use case would be if they zoomed in to far or off of the chart line completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true)` you will see three buttons on the bottom right side of the screen. One of them does what you need.

Otherwise, you can call `chartView.zoomReset()` in order to programmatically trigger this.